# Can I use hadoop jar command to run normal java programs as well?

Tags: java, hadoop

I have some hadoop file system operations (eg: `hdfs mkdir`) in my Java code. When I tried to run java program using `java -cp`, the directory got created in linux local file system. So I run program with hadoop jar command and directory got created in hdfs. Now I am planning to run the entire java program using hadoop jar command. I am wondering would there be any issue by using hadoop jar command especially when reading files from local folders or executing `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(some linux command);` Below if the snippet of the code for my hdfs file operations

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();       
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
boolean res = fs.mkdirs(directory path);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, hadoop jar command can be used to run normal java programs as well. But the opposite is wrong. Hadoop file system operations can only be run in hadoop environment. But if you are running in a hadoop cluster, the linux commands may get executed in slave nodes.

Comment: Apparently it seems like I can't specify external dependant jars if i use hadoop jar command. Please note that I don't have any map reduce code, i just have some hdfs file operations.

Comment: Yes , external dependent jars can also be used while running in hadoop environment. It can be done in different ways. Either you can create a uber jar with all your dependencies, or distribute the dependent jars in each node and define the path in $HADOOP_CLASSPATH variable.

Comment: I was trying for a different solution since i don't have administrative privileges. I don't want to build a fat jar either as it will grow my deployment jar and will be redundant. Is there a´way by which i can specify configurations in my new Configuration() object so that i can write into HDFS directly?